# Having trouble accessing variable

Tags: variables, struct, private

I want to find the address of one of the structure's data members, but I'm having trouble accessing its variables. Is there of a solution that donesn't require me to change the struct in any way?

h file

```
class C
{
private:
    int   x;     
    char  b;     
};
```

cpp file.

```
char *p2 = new char[128];
memset(p2,'aa',128);
Test_C *r2 = new(p2) Test_C[3];
```

//inside for loop

```
printf("Address: 0x%x, Value of b: %x \n",&r2[i]->b, r[i].r=0x50);
```

I'm getting the error at &r2[i]->b;

Also some code review would be nice :) I'm planing on outputting values of the C struct with padding

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have posted a C++ class and not a C struct.

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/):

> private members of a class are accessible only from within other
>   members of the same class or from their friends.

So, to answer your question, you cannot access those private members from outside the class without modifying the class itself (to include public accessors, for instance).